# ASP.NET Control visibility dilemma

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, visibility, objectdatasource

I've got a `Page`, a `GridView` using an `ObjectDataSource` with a `SelectMethod` and a `DropDownList`. The `SelectMethod`, among other things, gets a string-array containing several IDs (to filter the Data) - but I also need it as `DataSource` for the `DropDownList`.
Alas, I cannot `DataBind` the `DropDownList` inside the `SelectMethod` since it's null.
An Idea would be to bind this `string[]` to a `Session`-Variable, but then I'd have to either re-set it upon every `Page_Load` or remove it from `Session` on every other page if I want it to update in case something on the Database changed.

What I'm looking for is some kind of variable that is available both in `Page_Load` and my `ObjectDataSource`s `SelectMethod`, but that removes itself upon leaving the page (i.e. navigating to any other page on my Web-Application (preferably without having to call a method on EVERY other Page).

I hope you could understand my problem.

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: So your select method selects data for a GridView and data for DropDownList at the same time? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: No, no. It selects Data for my GridView, I just want the string array that I fetch inside the Select Method (that is used to filter entries out of the DataTable that I return for my GridView) to be the DataSource for the DropDownList

Comment: @PaulieWaulie, ViewState doesn't contain any entries inside the SelectMethod unfortunately.

Comment: Still does not make sense to me. Is the dropdown in a grid view row? If not why does the select method load its values?

Comment: It does that because I want to avoid performing the same WebService-Call (that fetches the string array) twice, so if I can already fetch the values at one point - why do it again?

Comment: Obviously I can do that call inside PageLoad or anywhere else (and bind the DropDown there too), but then I need some kind of variable that retains its values for the SelectMethod to see it but loses them once I e.g. leave the page, which brings me to my original dilemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the need to fetch the string array arises from the performance hit that a separate roundtrip will cause. To work around this you may create a separate object to feed your object data source. This object will have two methods one for getting the string array and another for getting the data for the grid (i.e. the select method)

You may then put an object like this in your page and fetch the data in it in a lazy manner. If the object makes a call for any of the data it stores the other part in a field. You can then use the ObjectDataSource ObjectCreating event to pass this object on your page to the ObjectDataSource

```
protected void odsSomething_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    e.ObjectInstance = YourInsntanceAlreadyInThePage;
}
```

This way you will avoid the roundtrip.

Also consider making two web service calls at the same time using the asynchronous client calls so that you can make both calls for the same time. If this is viable depends on the flow of your logic.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm looking for is some kind of variable that is available both in Page_`Load` and my `ObjectDataSource`'s `SelectMethod`, but that removes itself upon leaving the page (i.e. navigating to any other page on my Web-Application (preferably without having to call a method on EVERY other Page).

In a similar situation, I've used the `Items` property of the current `HttpContext`. It's an `IDictionary` (non-generic), so can hold arbitrary `object`s keyed by arbitrary `object`s, and its lifetime is precisely the duration of the current request, so will go away as soon as the request is ended. To use:

```
// Where you first get the data
HttpContext.Current.Items["SomeKey"] = new [] { "string1", "string2" };

// Where you want to to use the data
var strings = (string[])HttpContext.Current.Items["SomeKey"];
```